# Any QTI2.0 Standard XML document for Error handling?

Tags: php

I am currently working on a quiz project by following **QTI2.0** Standard. I can find all the standards & schema for all types [ Choice, True or False , Matching etc ] from the website [**IMS GLOBAL**](http://imsglobal.org/question/). Now i want to pass the errors and exceptions. For this, i want to know is there any QTI2.0 standard for error handling?

Because i cannot write my own structure for this error handling. I have to stick with this standard only.

So, if anyone worked on QTI before, kindly suggest me.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you need, perhaps this can help: [PHP AJAX quiz library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/quizzy/)

Comment: I will upvote your question though I have no idea about it but, it definitely shows that we need to dig in.. Thanks for letting us know about such standard!

Comment: Still now i am not able to find. It seems no one has worked before on this. I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what sort of error you are looking to handle. Most errors are handled at higher (or lower) levels than the QTI specification, so it doesn't need much.

For the errors that exist at the QTI standard layer, the [QTI 2.0 Implementation Guide](http://www.imsglobal.org/question/qti_v2p0/imsqti_implv2p0.html) defines only errors that are basically wrong answers. Sections 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6 allow you to provide feedback on wrong/invalid/corrupt answers, and specify what that will result in - a wrong answer, a chance to try again, an altered question/answer pair to present back to the test taker...etc.

For instance, if there is some error that passes the answer of "5" when the multiple choice question had no such option, you can use Response Processing, Feedback, or Adaptive Items to talk back to the test taker and inform them something is wrong, to try again, or whatever is application to your/their situation.

If you are looking to handle things like connection handshake errors, formatting problems, invalid XML markup, etc, the QTI doesn't provide guidance because that's outside the scope of the standard. For that you'd have to refer to standard programming practice, XML/DTD/XSL processing/validation standards, etc.

I hope this helps in some way!

Comment: Thank God. Finally i got a suggestion for this question. I wanted to handle some programming errors only. But from your answer, i came to know it is not possible. Anyway thanks for answering my question.